# Known Markov-type inequalities on entropy?

Tags: probability, entropy

Let $P$ be discrete distribution where the $i$-th value has probability $p_i$.
Define $H$ as the random variable returning $-\log(p_i)$ with probability $p_i$.

By definition, ${E}(H) = \mathrm{H}(P)$. 
Is any non-trivial upper bound on ${Pr}(H \geq a{E}(H)+b)$ is known which is independent of the distribution 
$P$?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by what is meant by "Markov-type" inequality here. Markov's inequality says that $\mathrm{Pr}(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a}$, whereas you are asking about $\mathrm{Pr}(H \leq a E(H) + b)$.

Comment: It also doesn't seem your stated probability can be non-trivially bounded independent of distribution in general for plain old expectation either. Consider for example, $X_p \in \{-\frac{1}{1-p},\frac1p\}$ with $P(X_p = -\frac{1}{1-p} = 1-p$ and $P(X_p) = \frac1p = p$. Then $E[X_p] = p$ for all $p \in (0,1)$, but $P(X_p \leq E[X_p]) = 1-p$ which can be made arbitrary.

Comment: The side of the inequality was wrong, sorry, I edited it now...

Comment: Reversing the sign of the inequality does not change my example above beyond some trivial modifications. Just let $X_p \in \left\{-\frac1p,\frac1{1-p}\right\}$ with $P\left(X_p = -\frac1p\right) = p$ and $P\left(X_p = \frac1{1-p}\right) = \frac1{1-p}$. Now, the argument is the same as before, but with the inequality flipped.

Answer (score 0):

The following counterexample will show that the inequality you ask about, as stated, cannot be non-trivially bounded (i.e. restrictions on a and b must be made). If $X \sim Ber(p)$, then for $p > 0.5$, we have that $H_1 < H_0$ where $H_i$ is the value of $H$ when $X = i$. Thus, $\mathrm{Pr}(H \leq E[H]) = \mathrm{Pr}(X = 1) = p$. Since $p$ can be made arbitrarily close to 1, we have that the only possible bound is the trivial one.

Another example can also show that a lower bound is also not possible. To do this, consider fixed $n$ and consider $X \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $p_n > \frac1n$ and $p_i = \frac{1-p_n}{n} < p_n$ for $i \neq n$. Then we have that $H_i > H_n$ for all $i \neq n$ by the monotonicity of $-\log$. But then we have that $\mathrm{Pr}(H \geq E[H]) = \mathrm{Pr}(X \neq n) = 1 - p_n$. But for each $n$, we can make $1 - p_n$ arbitrarily close to $\frac1n$ and sending $n$ to $\infty$, we get that we can make this probability arbitrarily close to 1.

Edit: For $a > 1$, however, we can get a non-trivial bound for $P(H \geq a E[H])$ by simply applying Markov's inequality:
$$P(H \geq a E[H]) \leq \frac{E[H]}{a E[H]} = \frac1a$$.

Comment: The side of the inequality was indeed wrong and I was looking for an upper bound.  In the upper bound case, though, even in your first example it holds that Pr(H<=kE[H]) is exponentially decreasing in k.

Comment: The property of being exponentially decreasing in k is independent of the question as you asked it. You asked about bounds on $P(H \leq a E[H] + b)$, not about rates of change as you vary $a$.